# no lcid in tenant.createsite

Tags: sharepoint, csom

We can use the create site method of the Tenant class to create a new site collection in CSOM. This takes SiteCreationProperties object as parameter. we can specify the LCID here but this is optional

if you specify no lcid in tenant.createsite in which language will the new site collection be created

Answer (score 0):

It will be your default language in SharePoint